# SPF Record for Amazon EC2 and preventing emails being marked as spam

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, dns, spam-prevention, spf

I'm trying to sort out my Amazon EC2 to allow emails to be sent via my main server.

Currently the SPF record for the main website/server is as follows::

```
website.com.    300 IN  TXT "v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:1.1.1.1 ~all"
```

We have an Elastic IP setup on the AWS to give us a static IP of `2.2.2.2` so we have the following DNS A Type record setup:

```
test.website.com.   300 IN  A   2.2.2.2
```

I would have thought the following SPF record would allow both the main server and the AWS server to use SMTP emails...

```
test.website.com.   300 IN  TXT v=spf1 +a +mx +ip4:1.1.1.1 ip4:2.2.2.2 ~all
```

But, it doesn't, emails are still returning with

```
 Content analysis details:   (8.5 points, 5.0 required)

  pts rule name              description
 ---- ---------------------- --------------------------------------------------
  1.5 SPF_SOFTFAIL           SPF: sender does not match SPF record (softfail)
  1.1 DATE_IN_PAST_06_12     Date: is 6 to 12 hours before Received: date
  2.6 RDNS_DYNAMIC           Delivered to internal network by host with
                             dynamic-looking rDNS
  3.2 HELO_DYNAMIC_IPADDR    Relay HELO'd using suspicious hostname (IP addr
                             1)
```

I am pretty sure that all 4 of those are related to the same issue with the SPF miss-match

The Public DNS of the AWS instance is:

```
 ec2-2-2-2-2.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

We're not sure how the correct way to setup the DNS record...

- Do I add the Public DNS via an `a:ec2-2-2-2-2.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`
- Do I add the Public DNS via an `include:ec2-2-2-2-2.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com`
- Should I be using `-all` or `~all` or `+all` or `?all`
- Should I be using a `+` symbol before each of the variables or not, for example `+mx` or just `mx`

Comment: Given you're already on AWS, have you considered just sending your mail via SES?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first option would be to send your emails using the Simple Email Service which is what is used for sending emails from AWS WorkMail, however if you need to send emails from your own EC2 instance then you need to configure reverse DNS as well as forward DNS.

1. Ensure you have a Route 53 A record for your EC2 instance with the mail server on it. This A record should resolve to the Elastic IP you have configured.
2. Then go to the form https://aws.amazon.com/forms/ec2-email-limit-rdns-request?catalog=true&isauthcode=true and enter the use case description for your need to send emails from EC2, and the Elastic IP address for your EC2 instance, and what you want the reverse DNS to be. The reverse DNS record and the forward DNS A record should be the same, eg:

EC2-instance-name Elastic IP 2.2.2.2

Forward DNS    mail.domain.com A 2.2.2.2

Reverse DNS 2.2.2.2 PTR mail.domain.com

AWS applies this restriction to ensure the quality of AWS IP addresses and in an attempt to ensure AWS infrastructure is not used to send SPAM emails. When they assess your business case if they think there is an alternate AWS resource which could do what you are wanting to do better then they may suggest it but in my experience unless your use case is way out there they will tend to approve it.

I have setup exchange and linux-based mail servers in the past as well as a few mailing list servers and they all needed reverse DNS working properly, I filled out the form, and the reverse DNS was approved within a short amount of time.

Comment: So for a forward DNS should that be an a record or a cname record? as for the reverse dns they would set that up? Also, I'm not using Route53.

Comment: It doesn't matter who your DNS provider is. You first need t create a forward record in your DNS hosting for the mail server, once that has been done fill out the form on the AWS portal and they will creat the PTR record for your IP address.